# sql select distinct with two parameters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql query in sql view. Database mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `table`.`date`
    `table`.`name` 
FROM
    `table`
```

I need to understand:
Do we select all records with **unique** `date` and **unique** `name`
Or only one of the parameters must be unique.

Let's say I have 3 records:

```
  date="11.04.15" name="xxx"

  date="11.04.15" name="yyy"
  date="11.04.15" name="yyy"
```

Will it select first two records?

Comment: what data base ?

Comment: The entire touple / record will be unique, so the combination of returned columns. However, you should **tag** the correct database in your question as already noted above.

Comment: There is no `WHERE` clause so your query will return both records.

Comment: Also this is simple enough to try yourself. Create a table, add the 3 records, execute the select. What do you see in the result set?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT a, b` selects unique combinations of (a,b).

Comment: There is nothing here that you couldn't test for yourself in less time than it took to ask :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will select all records which have unique date + name entry, so yes, the 2 records will appears

Comment: it will take the 2 first records then